# Moving files into subfolders according to partial filename with VBA

Tags: vba, file, filenames, move, partial

I have been trying to move over 300+ pdf files to subfolders, which partially match filenames. The file names format is as follow:

```
Definition, PN 123456, SN unique
Definition(may change), PN 657634(may change), SN unique(always different)
```

Their pattern is two commas followed by PN and SN: ..., PN ..., SN ...

The folder names are: `PN 123456 SN unique`.

The example:

filenames

```
VALVE AFT SAFETY, PN 81155B010101, SN 00515
CABIN PRESSURIZATION MODULE, PN 92147A020103, SN 00501
AIR CYCLE MACHINE, PN 820906-3, SN 2010010011
AIR CYCLE MACHINE, PN 820906-3, SN 2010010014
TEMP REDUCTION SWITCH, PN 820907-2, SN 0414
```

folder names

```
PN 81155B010101 SN 00515
PN 92147A020103 SN 00501
PN 820906-3 SN 2010010011
PN 820906-3 SN 2010010014
PN 820907-2 SN 0414
```

The folders are subdirectories, second level.

I tried the information that, was kindly provided by @BNR bnr.455560 here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/moving-files-to-a-subfolder-based-on-partial-filename-with-vba.1120135/

My original post:  https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/moving-files-to-a-subfolder-based-on-partial-filename-with-vba.1221014/

The below code run as Macro - does nothing.

```vb
Public Function Return_SubDirectory_Name(FileName As String) As String
    
    'define a string array
    Dim Splitter() As String
    
    ' check if we have a filename with a length > 0  - i.e. no empty filenames
    If Len(FileName) > 0 Then
        ' let's assume the filename is "Definition, PN 123456, SN unique.pdf"
        ' Split creates a string array with the ", " as the break point - notice the space before and after the "-" character
        ' element 0 in the array will hold "Definition"
        ' element 2 in the array will hold "SN inique.pdf
        Splitter = Split(FileName, ", ", 2)
        
        ' test to make sure the array has JUST two elements
        ' 1st element of ANY array starts with zero
        ' logic would need to be adjusted if file name was something like "02 - 12345 - 123.pdf" - as plsit function would create more elements
        If UBound(Splitter) = 1 Then
            
            ' now splitter (1) holds the value "PN 123456, SN unique.pdf"
            ' split out the ".pdf" or whatever file extention

            Splitter = Split(Splitter(1), ".")
            ' element (0) now just holds "PN 123456, SN unique" - this *SHOULD* be the sub directory or deal #
 
'Remove comma "," by replace it to ""
            Splitter = Replace(Splitter(0), ",", "")
            Return_SubDirectory_Name = CStr(Splitter(0))
            
            ' now exit the function
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        ' if above logic didn't work (maybe weird file name or whatever) - then drop out here with vbnullstring (empty) filename
        Return_SubDirectory_Name = vbNullString
    
    End If
    
End Function

Public Sub Check_Files(Search_Path As String)

    Dim File_Name As String
    Dim File_Type As String
    
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim Deal_Name As String
    
    Dim Archive_Path As String
    Dim Target_Path As String
    
    Dim File_Count As Integer
    
    ' setup where the archive directory is - maybe a network location?
    ' I'll assume it is the same directory path as the work book - change the following path as required
    ' path should be in a format like "C:\Desktop\MyFiles" or something
    Archive_Path = ThisWorkbook.Path
    
    ' the search_path is handed into the function as an argument
    ' checks the Search path - this path is where the file currently are - maybe different than where you want to archive them
    Confirm_Directory Search_Path
    
    ' changes excel's default directory path to the one you want to search
    ChDir Search_Path

    ' assumes .msg files, but could be .pdf files - make changes as needed
    File_Type = Search_Path & "*.pdf"

    ' identifies file name within the target directory
    strFileName = Dir(File_Type)
    
    ' cycles through each file within the search directory - will continue until the length of the strFileName = 0 (i.e. no files)
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        
        ' get the sub directory or #deal name
        Deal_Name = Return_SubDirectory_Name(strFileName)
        
        ' test if we have a valid deal name (not a vbnullstring)
        If Len(Deal_Name) > 0 Then
        
            ' update the target_path - the target path will change as the different #deal name subdirectories within the archive path change
            Target_Path = Archive_Path & "\" & Deal_Name
        
            ' checks if THAT target archive path exists - makes one if it doesn't
            Confirm_Directory Target_Path
            
            ' copy required file to the target archive directory
            FileCopy Search_Path & "\" & strFileName, Target_Path & "\" & strFileName

            ' delete original copy from search directory
            Kill Search_Path & "\" & strFileName
        
            File_Count = File_Count + 1
        
        End If
        
        ' aquires the next filename in the search directory
        strFileName = Dir
        
    Loop

    Debug.Print "Moved " & File_Count & " file(s)"

End Sub

Public Sub Confirm_Directory(This_Path As String)
    ' used to test for directory locations
    ' will make sub directories if required
    
    Dim Splitter() As String
    Dim Test_Path As String
    
    If Dir(This_Path, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    
        Splitter = Split(This_Path, "\")
        
        For I = LBound(Splitter) To UBound(Splitter)
            If I = 0 Then
                Test_Path = Splitter(0)
            Else
                Test_Path = Test_Path & "\" & Splitter(I)
            End If
            
ReTest:
            If Dir(Test_Path, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
                'Debug.Print "'" & Test_Path & "' does not exist"
                MkDir Test_Path
                'Debug.Print "Making ' " & Test_Path & "'"
                GoTo ReTest
            Else
                'Debug.Print "'" & Test_Path & "' exists"
            End If
        Next I
    End If
    

End Sub

Sub Sort_files_2_folders_()

End Sub
```

Comment: You've not said anything explicitly about what the rules are for moving the files.  Should we assume that the last part of the filename (after "SN") needs to match exactly to the last part of the folder name (also after the "SN") ?  Is that all?

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you for your comment. That’s right the filename's last part after ‘SN’ to be matched to the one after ‘SN’ of the folder.

Comment: The current submitted code has been adjusted to matchup the fully folder name. Since it will also suit to my purpose. I was trying to make it works.

Comment: Are the folder names (the part after SN) all unique?  A file could never be a candidate for >1 folder?

Comment: @TimWilliams, Yes they are, unique. The file needs go to > 2 folder.

Comment: @TimWilliams, This works great! Thank you very much. It moves files into any subfolder, if 'SN' matched - exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out (adjust file paths as needed)

```vb
Sub RelocateFiles()
     Dim allFiles As Collection    'of File objects
     Dim allFolders As Collection  'of Folder objects
     Dim f As Object, fld As Object, sn As String, bMoved As Boolean
     
     'find all files (include subfolders)
     Set allFiles = GetFiles("C:\Temp\TestFiles\", "*.pdf", True)
     
     'find all destination folders
     Set allFolders = GetFolders("C:\Temp\TestFiles\", True)
     
     For Each f In allFiles   'loop over files
        sn = GetSN(f.Name)    'get SN part of name
        bMoved = False        'reset flag
        If Len(sn) > 0 Then   'has "sn" part ?
            For Each fld In allFolders        'loop over folders
                If GetSN(fld.Name) = sn Then  'check folder name
                    Debug.Print "Moving '" & f.Name & _
                            "' to '" & fld.Path & "'"
                    f.Move fld.Path & "\"     'move the files
                    bMoved = True             'flag moved
                    Exit For                  'stop checking
                End If
            Next fld
        End If
        If Not bMoved Then Debug.Print "## Not moved: " & f.Name
     Next f
End Sub

'Return the "sn" part for a folder or file name
Function GetSN(txt As String) As String
    Dim arr, sn, pos As Long
    arr = Split(txt, " SN ")
    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
        sn = arr(UBound(arr))
        pos = InStr(sn, ".") 'any extension? (if a filename)
        If pos > 0 Then sn = Left(sn, pos - 1) 'remove extension
        GetSN = sn
    End If
End Function

'Find all folders under `startFolder`
'  Returns a collection of Folder objects
Function GetFolders(startFolder As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Object
    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr, fpath
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
            If subFolders Then colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            colFolders.Add fso.getfolder(subFldr.Path)
        Next subFldr
    Loop
    Set GetFolders = colFolders
End Function

'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetFiles(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr, fpath
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        
        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
        
        fpath = fldr.Path
        If Right(fpath, 1) <> "\" Then fpath = fpath & "\"
        f = Dir(fpath & filePattern) 'Dir is faster...
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            colFiles.Add fso.getfile(fpath & f)
            f = Dir()
        Loop
    Loop
    Set GetFiles = colFiles
End Function
```